# How to display the all input even numbers to the <p> using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm a beginner in javascript. I ask a question on how to store the even numbers and display all the input even numbers into a `<p>` tag. For example, I input `4` so that the `<p>` displays `4`. Then if I input again for example `6` so that `<p>` will become `4,6`.
Is it possible to do it?

```js
    function number(){

        var number = document.getElementById("number").value;

        if(number%2===0){
            alert("Your number is Even");
            var numbers=[];
                numbers.push(number);

            document.getElementById("display_even").innerHTML=numbers;

        }
        else
            alert("Please Insert Even number");
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="number">
<button type="submit" onclick="number()">Click</button>

<p id="display_even"></p>
```

Comment: _"Is it possible to do it?"_ - Yes, but not with a local array that get's "reset" on every call of `number()`. You don't need that array at all. Have a look at the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you are re-initialising your `numbers` array in every call to the `number` function. You can fix that by making it a property of the function and only initialising it if it is undefined. Then you can use `join` to convert the array into a comma separated list (although this is not strictly necessary as array to string conversion will do that for you anyway):

```js
function number() {
  this.numbers = this.numbers || [];
  var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
//        alert("Your number is Even");
    numbers.push(number);
    document.getElementById("display_even").innerHTML = numbers.join(',');
  }
  else {
    alert("Please Insert Even number");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="number">
<button type="submit" onclick="number()">Click</button>

<p id="display_even"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a very simple thing. Each time when a user is entering a number and running the function, the number of values inside the array is set to 0. The simplest solution is to declare the array outside of the function:

```js
var numbers=[];    
function number(){

        var number = document.getElementById("number").value;

        if(number%2===0){
            alert("Your number is Even");
            
                numbers.push(number);

            document.getElementById("display_even").innerHTML=numbers;

        }
        else
            alert("Please Insert Even number");
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="number">
<button type="submit" onclick="number()">Click</button>

<p id="display_even"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function number(){

        var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
        if(number%2===0){
            alert("Your number is Even");
             var num = document.getElementById("display_even").textContent;
            var numbers=[];
                if(num){
                numbers.push(num);
                }
                numbers.push(number);

            document.getElementById("display_even").innerHTML=numbers;

        }
        else
            alert("Please Insert Even number");
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="number">
<button type="submit" onclick="number()">Click</button>

<p id="display_even"></p>
```